# IllegalStateException in HttpChannel.handle in Jetty

Tags: jetty, http2

My logs are getting full of exceptions like this:

```
8884902 [qtp1075738627-4458] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /upload 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
78884902 [qtp1075738627-4458] WARN  o.e.j.u.t.strategy.EatWhatYouKill -  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=IDLE rs=COMPLETED os=ABORTED is=READY awp=false se=false i=false al=0
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState.unhandle(HttpChannelState.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:538)
```

even though the system seems to be working normally. It's a bit concerning that "normal" operation would include a flood of such logs. I can't find anyone else getting exceptions like this.
This is all on the current version of Jetty, with a Spring Boot 2.3.1 application, using the http2 connector. It happens on a few different URIs in the application with no clear pattern.
Any ideas on this? I don't want to accept having non-stop exceptions as normal behavior of this system.

Looking through the source of HttpChannelState I can see that the exception is formed from:

```
("s=%s i=%b a=%s",_state,_initial,_async);
```

But I can't trace much further what this means.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of Servlet Async Processing or Servlet Async I/O could be the cause.

The output stream being aborted like that is very odd as well.

The origin (in the code) for the `8884902 [qtp1075738627-4458] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /upload  java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

is https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.31.v20200723/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpChannel.java#L600

But why it doesn't have a stacktrace is also bizarre.

You should file this as an issue at the Eclipse Jetty issue tracker https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues and work with us to get to the bottom of your issue.

If you can replicate easily enough that would make things easier to troubleshoot.

Since you are using HTTP2, make sure you upgrade both your version of Java and Eclipse Jetty.